# Ajax call is not going to controller

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

This is form of register:

```
              <form name="signupForm" class="signupForm"
                         >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobilePhone"
                                   id="mobile-phone" placeholder="Mobil Tel">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"
                                   placeholder="İsim">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="last-name"
                                   placeholder="Soy İsim">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tckn" id="tckn"
                                   placeholder="TCKN">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="e-mail"
                                   placeholder="E-posta">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="pwdMask">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"
                                       placeholder="Şifre"> <span
                                    class="fa fa-eye-slash pwd-toggle"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button id="registerBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button">Kayıt
                                ol
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

For the button, i defined this behavior:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


    $('#registerBtn').click(
 function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            fireRegisterAccount();
 function fireRegisterAccount() {

                var mobilePhone = $('#mobile-phone').val();
                var name = $('#name').val();
                var lastName = $('#last-name').val();
                var tckn = $('#tckn').val();
                var email = $('#e-mail').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();

                var data = "mobilePhone=" + mobilePhone +
                    "&name=" + name
                    + "&lastName=" + lastName
                    + "&tckn=" + tckn
                    + "&email=" + email
                    + "&password=" + password;

                console.log("data paramters:"+data);


                $.ajax({
                    url: '/register',
                    data: data,
                    type: "POST",

                    success: function (response) {
                        debugger
                        console.log("response: " + response);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        debugger
                        console.log("fail")
                    }
                });



            }

        });


</script>
```

But it does not go to spring- boot controller.

Instead of it, i see that in console of browser, it retrieves same page:

```
response: <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="tr"> <head>
    <!-- Basic Page Needs
      ================================================== -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatibl
```

What is the problem? Library ?

Js and html in same class.

Also i have this in body of html:

```
<!-- initialize jQuery Library -->
<script src="landing/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- for Bootstrap js -->
<script src="landing/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom js-->
<script src="landing/js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="landing/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
```

When i click, i see no error. It makes a call but no to my controller. Because it is not going to debug.

It is not about so much parameters because i reduced to one but still same.

I also tried this but still same:

```
    var baseurl = $('body').data('baseurl');
$("#savecountry").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseurl+'/Country/SaveCountry',
```

When i inspect, i see this with 302 status code:

```
http://localhost:8080/?mobilePhone=5427886263&name=fsa&lastName=qq&tckn=21321&email=5324367390&password=asfas
```

Backend controller:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResultLang registerToSystem(
            @RequestParam("mobilePhone") String mobilePhone,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("lastName") String lastName,
            @RequestParam("tckn") String tckn,
            @RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("password") String password,
            HttpServletRequest request){
//code but does not come here
}
```

Also all those inputs are in a data panel:

```
 data-panel=".panel-signup"
```

called from top of it:

```
<a class="lnk-toggler"
                                                  data-panel=".panel-signup" href="#">Kayıt ol!</a>
```

Can it be reason?

It also calls 
http://localhost:8080/login
when i look at network tab of browser. But it should not call. There is nowhere to call it.

Datapanel of register belongs to login panel but i removed action:login to see . SO it should not go to login

Comment: Show the controller's method signature and annotations, please

Comment: @acdcjunior added to end of question.

Comment: In your js code you have `/registerr` and in controller you have `/register`.

Comment: @htshame it is copy paste error. They are same.

Comment: At what URL (host+port+path) is the HTML page running? At what URL is that `/register` controller responding to? `http://localhost:8080/register`? And what is the value for `baseurl`?

Comment: base url is localhost:8080